# Changing a class name with jquery-js when resize screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slicknav

i have in my site a 3 menu .

desktop= classic html menu + superfish jquery

mobile= have slicknav jquery menu (include every menu of desktop)

now my problem is include the static menu of superfish on slicknav.

for this i want create a condition to change the class of superfish menu with the class of slicknav when the screen size reduce.

the problem: when try to use a example a simple script for change the class not work:

```
<script>

function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
    $("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu cambioclasse2');
    }
    else {
    $("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu sf-menu');
    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize(); // call once initially

</script>
```

this is a example of menu

```
  <div id="header" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="top-menu">

    <ul id="nullo" class="sf-menu">
      <li>
        <a class="tito" href="/amministra/"><img src="/inc/files/images/adminplus.png"></a><div class="ams">AMMINISTRA</div>

           <ul>
                                        <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_commerciale/" title="">
                              Commerciale                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_eccellenze/" title="">
                              Eccellenze                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_aree/" title="">
                              Aree                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_contabile/" title="">
                              Contabile                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_certificazioni/" title="">
                              Certificazioni                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_compensi/" title="">
                              Compensi                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_trattative/" title="">
                              Trattative                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_club/" title="">
                              Club                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_guida/" title="">
                              Guida                         </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_pagine/" title="">
                              Pagine                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_mailing/" title="">
                              Mailing                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_report/" title="">
                              Report                            </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_batching/" title="">
                              Batching                          </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_temi_seo/" title="">
                              Classificazione                           </a>
                        </li>
                                                <li>
                            <a class="tab_amministra" href="/amministra/gestione_visite_pagine/" title="">
                              VIsite pagine                         </a>
                        </li>
                                   </ul>
      </li>
</ul>


          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/vacanze_weekend/">
                Vacanze             </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/matrimoni/">
                Matrimoni               </a>
            </li>
                        <li>
                <a href="/meeting/">
                Meeting             </a>
            </li>

          </li>

                    <li></li>
```

this bacause slicknav rebuild the output of menu without id , so the script not work because not exist the id "nullo"

now how create condition with only  class and not with id ??

or  can apply a change to slicknav?

**update:**: i tested this script, and this work if open page page in large screen(superfish) and after reduce in mobile screen (slicknav), but not work if open the page with small size(slicknav) and after go in large screen(superfish).

```
<script>

function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
    $("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu sf-menu');
    }
    else {

    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize(); // call once initially

</script>


<script>

 function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
        $(".sf-menu").toggleClass('sf-menu cambioclasse2');

    }
    else {

    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize();

</script>
```

why ?

**solved with this abnormal code,how can I optimize it?:**

```
<script>

if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
  $("#nullo").toggleClass('cambioclasse2 sf-menu');
}
else {

}


</script>





<script>

 function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
        $("#nullo").toggleClass('cambioclasse2 sf-menu');

    }
    else {

    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize();

</script>




<script>

function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() > 739) {     
    $("#nullo").toggleClass('sf-menu sf-menu');
    }
    else {

    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize(); // call once initially

</script>


<script>

 function resize() {
    if ( $(window).width() < 739) {     
        $(".sf-menu").toggleClass('sf-menu cambioclasse2');

    }
    else {

    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 739) {     
        $(".sf-menu").toggleClass('sf-menu cambioclasse2');
    }
    else {
        $(".cambioclasse2").toggleClass('cambioclasse2 sf-menu');
    }
}
$(window).on("resize", resize);
resize();
```

This function should prove for a smaller better adaptation of the abnormal code. since it will only change the element's class if it needs to and wont modify it if it is already in the correct class.

Comment: thanks for answer but not work, i tried another script and with this work only from desktop to mobile, please read my update in first post, thanks

Comment: Like i said if your use $(".sf-menu") and then use .toggleClass on the element, the script will not work the second time, because $(".sf-menu") will no longer exist because it will now be cambioclass2. try the second part i suggested by adding the class and removing it, and then adjust your cambioclass2 class to override the styles of the sf-menu class where you require

Comment: have solved with an abnormal code, you can improve this reduced-code?, view first post

Comment: I have added a smaller version which you can include at the top which should should replace all the others